# Is I-nex temp reading accurate

Tags: 14.04, cpu, temperature, amd-processor

I got I-nex and I was wondering if the cpu temperature is accurate. I have a fx-4150 and wanted to do a slight overclock. My computer is pretty much idle with only I-nex open. It says my cpu temp is about 2c. Is that ok and if I overclock is the temperature reading accurate? Also at the most it went to 10c, sometimes 5c.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you have a water cooling setup such low temperatures are possible if you´re air cooling than your telemetric data is definitely incorrect. The best thing is to check your BIOS data: if it´s displaying +/- 10 °C you can go on. The measured temperature also depends on your sensor location. A thermometer inside the CPU can measure 60 °C while at the same time a thermometer at a different spot inside the CPU could only measure 30 °C.
For an AMD fx-4150 a temperature of 70 °C is definitely fine and for a short period of time it also can handle up to 95 °C but try to avoid very hight temperatures. Last but not least I highly recommend you to set up some kind of 'automatic emergency kill switch' inside your BIOS making it that if your CPU temperature reaches hight levels the BIOS automatically lowers the CPU frequency.